# Create repository in non-empty remote folder

Tags: apache, svn, version-control, debian, tortoisesvn

It's been 14 years since I last worked with svn and appearently I have forgotten everything...

I have an existing web-project, consisting of a bunch of php, html, js and other files in a directory tree on a V-Server. Now I want to take these folders under version control and create a copy on my local machine using svn. So I installed subversion according to these instructions: https://www.linuxcloudvps.com/blog/how-to-install-svn-server-on-debian-9/
Using the already-present apache2.

But now I kinda hit a roadblock. If I try `svnadmin create` on the existing folder, it tells me that is is not empty and does nothing really. All the questions and answers I find here and elsewhere are either
a) focussing on an already existing folder on the local machine
b) assuming more prior knowledge than I have right now aka I don't understand them.

Is there a step-by-step guide for dummies anywhere on how to do this? Or can anyone tell me in laymans terms how to do this?
I can't believe this case never comes up or that it is really very complicated.

Comment: You are confusing a [repository](https://subversion.apache.org/quick-start#what-is-a-repository) with a [working copy](https://subversion.apache.org/quick-start#what-is-a-working-copy).

Comment: Well, the working copy would be the files on my local machine right? But to check that out, I first need a repository somewhere to check the files out from. Right now, the files and folders I'd like to check out are just lying on a server. There is no repo there, no .svn etc. So setting up a repository to check out from in a non-empty existing folder, that is what I'm failing at.

Comment: You need to create a new empty repository with `svnadmin create REPONAME` then `svn import` your project's data to this repository.

Comment: That would be the standard procedure, yes, but then my files would be in another folder, the repo folder. I want my existing folder structure to be the repository.

Comment: Sorry but you're absolutely confusing repository and working copy. Seriously. The repository is just a database, you don't work with its files. You check out a working copy and those are the files you work with. That isn't negotiable, it's how Subversion works. If you want it to behave as git perhaps you can just install git, it really does the same stuff.

Comment: No, I'm not confusing those, but appearently I utterly fail at explaining what I'm trying to do. I know the wokring copy is what I check out to modify and then check in again. But afaik the repository is not really a database but a file structure on a server where the code files are stored. And this I already have. I do have a server with all my code files and a local copy on my machine. But atm I just copy them back and forth via SFTP instead of using svn. And I don't want to use another directory on the server as respostitory because then I would need to also implement deployment prodecures.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of failing to understand your exact needs, I think you can proceed as follows. I'll use this terms:

- **Code**: it's the unversioned directory at V-Server where you currently have the bunch of php, html, js and other files
- **Repository**: it's the first "special" directory you need to create in order to store your Subversion history and potentially share it with others. There must be one and there can only be one.
- **Working copy**: it's the second "special" directory you need to create in order to work with your php, html, js... files once they are versioned and it'll be linked to a given path and revision of your repository. At a given time there can be zero, one or many of them.

Your **code** can become a **working copy** or not, that's up to you, but it can never become a repository:

```
$ svnadmin create /path/to/code
svnadmin: E200011: Repository creation failed
svnadmin: E200011: Could not create top-level directory
svnadmin: E200011: '/path/to/code' exists and is non-empty
```

Your **repository** requires an empty folder but it can be located anywhere you like, as long as you have access to it from the machine you're going to use in your daily work. Access means it's located in your PC (thus you use the `file:` protocol) or it's reachable through a server you've installed and configured (`svn:`, `http:` or `https:`).

```
$ svnadmin create /path/to/repo
$
```

Your **working copies** can be created wherever you need to work with your IDE. It can be an empty directory (the usual scenario) or a non-empty one. The checkout command retrieves your files from the repo and puts them in the working copy so, at a later stage, you're able to run a commit command to submit your new and changed files to the repository. As you can figure out it isn't a good idea to create a working copy in random directories because incoming files will mix with existing files. There's however a special situation when it can make sense: when the repository location is new and is still empty. In that case you can choose between two approaches:

- If you want **code** to become a working copy, you can check out right into in and then make an initial commit to upload all files:

  ```
  $ svn checkout file://path/to/repo /path/to/code
  Checked out revision 0.
  $ svn add /path/to/code --force 
  A         code/index.php
  $ svn commit /path/to/code -m "Import existing codebase"
  $ Adding         /path/to/code/index.php
  $ Transmitting file data .done
  $ Committing transaction...
  $ Committed revision 1.
  ```
- If you don't care about **code** once it's stored in the repository or you want your working copy elsewhere, you can import your files from **code** and create a working copy in a fresh directory:

  ```
  $ svn import /path/to/code file://path/to/repo -m "Import existing codebase"
  Adding         code/index.php
  Committing transaction...
  Committed revision 1.
  $ svn checkout file://path/to/repo fresh
  A    fresh/index.php
  Checked out revision 1.
  ```